# Find dynamically created control (TextBox) in div

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a page in asp.net/vb.net where most divs are created dynamically. Furthermore I'd like the user to edit the content with dynamically inserted HtmlTextAreas, TextBoxes, etc.

I've already managed to create all of this stuff. I insert every div into a panel and after the user clicks on the edit button the divs are reloaded and filled with the items (e.g. TextBoxes). For saving, I'm looping through each div and try to find the item. The only problem that I have right now is, that somehow I'm unable to find the dynamically inserted items.

```
For Each control As HtmlGenericControl In panel.Controls
'do something like this:
'Dim textBox As New TextBox = control.FindControl("myTextBox")
Next
```

I've already tried some options, but unfortunately without success (TextBox is always Nothing)

I'm using Masterpages, so I tried this:

```
Dim MainContent As ContentPlaceHolder = TryCast(Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder"), ContentPlaceHolder)
Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast("myTextBox" & intCount.ToString(), TextBox)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for your time and effort! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful with your casting. When you have a collection of control objects you can't cast all of them to a textbox (ie a Label can't be converted and will throw an exception).

You can find controls using:

```
Dim textbox as TextBox = CType(control.FindControl("myTextBox"), TextBox)
```

To loop over all your textboxes you could use:

```
For Each textbox As TextBox In panel.Controls.OfType(of TextBox)
   ... interact here
Next
```

In this line

```
Dim textBox As TextBox = DirectCast("myTextBox" & intCount.ToString(), TextBox)
```

you are attempting to convert a string to a TextBox which wont work. You need to use FindControl to retrieve it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After searching again, I realised, that I wasn't recrating the elements correctly and because of that, the Controls won't load. Your code is working fine now.